# Artifactory mount repo as webdav share

Tags: windows, artifactory, webdav

i have the following problem.

i have a generic repo in artifactory (with username and password access).
i want to mount the artifactory repo as webdav share.

i use different webdav clients --> winscp, Cyberduck and so on.
For me it is possibly to mount the artifactory repo but the repo
is always readonly. It is not possibly to create an file.

Any ideas?

Best regards
mobios

Answer (score 0):

I understood that your use case is to connect to webdav share for both reads and write thru Artifactory? If this is the use case, it is not possible as [local repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Local+Repositories) in Artifactory do both read and write but the [remote repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Remote+Repositories) only performs the read and the file cannot be written to webdav share thru Artifactory. Kindly refer to this [article](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-is-a-remote-repository-and-how-does-it-work/) on how the remote repository works.

Comment: Thx for your answer Muhammed, But i use a local generic repo and cant only mount readonly. I dont use remote repo.

Comment: @mobios could you please elaborate on the use case then? I suspect I did not got it overall :)

Comment: Hi Muhammed, we have a few local generic repos. And we thought we can use this repos as webdav mounts to upload and Download data. In the jfrog documentation i can see it must be possible overall.